# NoSuchElement have tried every path type

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

I have trying to input an email into the login section of the page and can not get it to work.

I have the same error everytime "NoSuchElement"

The website is https://accela.kerncounty.com/CitizenAccess/Default.aspx

I have tried XPath, Name and ID

```
def wait(y):
    for x in range(y):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)


driver.get(website)
print("Website Loaded")
wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]").send_keys("xxx@gmail.com")
print("Input Email")
```

Comment: As per https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath, absolute XPath will break if the HTML changes slightly. So I think something might changing by js. So possible solution can be avoiding full XPath and using just XPath like //*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LoginBox_txtUserId"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. Element you trying to access is inside an iframe. So, you first have to switch into it in order to access elements there.
2. You need to use correct locators. `/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]` does not match nothing on that page. Locators must be short and clear, not absolute paths.
3. You need to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits, not a hardcoded sleeps.
   The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://accela.kerncounty.com/CitizenAccess/Default.aspx"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ACAFrame")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id*='LoginBox_txtUserId']"))).send_keys("xxx@gmail.com")
```

This is what this code does:
[image]

When finished working inside the iframe don't forget to switch back to the default content with:

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: שמחתי לעזור .